# BrowserModule imported twice

Tags: angular

Everyone knows that every angular application should have only one **`BrowserModule`** imported.

But somehow in my application it got imported twice. But angular didn't throw any error till now. When i added a child module and referenced it in the parent routing config via **`loadChildren`** it started to throw a runtime exception stating the same. Once i removed the second reference, everything started to work.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

CONFIGURATIONS:

```
"@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
"@angular/cli": "1.4.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3"
```

Comment: Have you declared your BrowserModule in your shared module?

Comment: it was not in shared module, it was in some different module

Answer (score 0):

well `loadChildren` suggests that you are using lazy loading - thus you won't get mentioned error on startup as that module is not yet loaded.

Comment: the module which i am  trying to load doesnt contain browserModule, some other module contained it

Comment: moreover i am not trying lazy load, i wanted to inject my child module routes to parent routing config file

Comment: But that lazy module might import something that have broser module - this it will be imported along with it.

Comment: It would be the best if you would share some of actual code .

Comment: yes, you are correct.. the child module, which i added newly and added loadChildren, imports some module which in-turn imports the module which has browserModule imported...but looks like some many other modules imports that module which has the browserModule imported. But angular didnt throw any error till now.

Comment: Singleton is a thing, that's why you have no errors

Comment: @JacopoSciampi can you explain a bit?

Comment: Singleton mean : Always the same istance, so when you provide a service in the main module, and inject it into components, angular will always get you the same istance, when you do, what you have done, with modules, instead of using a singleton, it will give you another istance

Comment: @JacopoSciampi be carefull with that "always" abusive world as this is not true it will always be the same instance. It all depends where provider is defined.

Comment: If you define your services in a module that is  lazy loaded you can be sure it will give you a new istance every time your load again your lazy loaded module

Comment: As you can see you use conditionals here - thus it is not always